# Vuetify grid column wrap fill full height

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

After creating component using v-card in grid system id does not fill to the full height. I used d-flex however it does not work as intended.

The middle column with white v-card should fill the whole column height however it stacks at the top.
Here is the picture of the desired functionality:
[image]

And here is the code, in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/mdygZgv) you can see that it does not extend to the full column height but is nested at the top.

```js
var car = Vue.component('car', {

  template: `
    <div class="car">
         <v-flex d-flex child-flex>
        <v-card >
            <v-card-text>
                <div class="text-center font-weight-black title text--primary">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    data
                </div>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        </v-flex>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    lorem: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel at clita quando. Te sit oratio vituperatoribus, nam ad ipsum posidonium mediocritatem, explicari dissentiunt cu mea. Repudiare disputationi vim in, mollis iriure nec cu, alienum argumentum ius ad. Pri eu justo aeque torquatos.`
  }),
  components: {"car":car}
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
      <v-layout row wrap>

        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>Card 1</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        
        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm2>

          <v-layout column wrap>
            <car></car>
            <car></car>
            <car></car>
          </v-layout>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm6>
          <v-card color="red lighten-2" dark tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem }} {{ lorem }} {{ lorem }} {{ lorem }} {{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
   
         <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
          <v-card color="purple lighten-1" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm2 child-flex>
          <v-card color="green lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        
        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm6 child-flex>
          <v-card color="blue lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}} {{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
       
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `car` component remove the first div.

```js
var car = Vue.component('car', {
  template: `
     <v-flex d-flex child-flex>
        <v-card >
            <v-card-text>
                <div class="text-center font-weight-black title text--primary">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    data
                </div>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
     </v-flex>
  `
})
```

Comment: But div is required part of the component construction in vue. When I remove it then I get error

Comment: @AlexT what error? I edited your codepen and I didn't get any error

Comment: But in vue.js you need to have root element which is <div> so it cannot be removed

Comment: @AlexT no, you need only one root element which could be an html element or a component

Answer (score 4):

You can add `grow` to the car outer div and `fill-height` to the v-flex...

```
<div class="car grow">
    <v-flex d-flex child-flex class="fill-height">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
            <div class="text-center font-weight-black title text--primary">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                data
            </div>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/qOKz9Qsv6L